# Service class and Intent Service class

Tags: android

I'm a newbie in android. Could anyone help me to find out tutorials which explains the situations when we need to extend Service and when to extend IntentService with examples.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope This one will help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample